# Draggable panel hides behind other panels

Tags: r, shiny

I made a draggable  panel but it hides behind other panels.

I change the variable `top`  in `absolutePanel` e.g., `1 ,0` or other natural numbers but it did not work. I am not sure how to use the variable `top`.

In addition, the draggable panel is clear,　transparent color and thus, it is hard to see.

How to display the draggable panel as the most top panel. 
 In addition, how to color it with NOT transparent colors.
 color.

The following is the example code of draggable panel.

The following figure  shows the draggable panel hides with some panel and in addition its color is transparent.
In the figure, there is an another draggable panel generated by the code `shinythemes::themeSelector()` and it is not transparent nor hides. So, I want to make such panel.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny::tags$head(
    shinythemes::themeSelector()

  ),#taghead
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins



    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(

      absolutePanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30),
        draggable = T
      ),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Using the css  style of @SeGa, I obtained the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use this css snippet:

```
css <- "
.ui-draggable {
 z-index: 100000;
 background-color: #cebfbf;
}"
```

and include it in the UI:

```
  shiny::tags$head(
    shinythemes::themeSelector(),
    tags$style(css)
  )
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you, your answer goes as above figure.  I will implement your css in my package, thank you.